# Firebird External Tables

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, data-import

I am trying to find a way to quickly load a lot of data into database and one suggested to use Firebird External Tables, I would like know more about this method, I've tried searching online but I'm not getting the useful information about this, I want to know how do they really work? Do the tables have to be exactly the same? and what if you are loading data from more than one database?

Comment: Where are you trying to load this data from? Are you transferring it from another database?

Comment: Yes I'm loading data from a table(s) and inserting it in another table which is in a different database

Comment: You can save the data from source to external table, and load it from another database. Or you can use external program, eg. Database Workbench has "datapump" feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use external tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ext1 EXTERNAL 'c:\myfile.txt'
(
field1 char(20),
field2 smallint
);
```

To do quick import into regular table, do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO realtable1 (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2 FROM ext1;
```

Remember to disable triggers and indexes (if possible) before loading, and reactivate them after.

This information is from Firebird FAQ: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq209/

Here's more information about using external tables, including information about file format: http://www.delphiman.de/Bin/UsingExternalFilesAsTables.pdf

Comment: When creating the table, do I have to make the fields exactly the same as the ones which I am inserting to??

Comment: @Fero68 No you don't (Firebird can do conversions just as when you do select from normal tables), but you have to be aware that the format of external file tables is very specific; technically it is a binary format, not a text format(!).

Comment: If he's exporting from another (Firebird) database using external tables, format will be correct automatically.

Comment: Hi when I try to insert into the external table, I get the follwong error "ISC ERROR CODE:335544831
ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
Access to external file "C:\TEMP\STOCK.TXT" is denied by server administrator"  and I have changed the ExternalFileAccess to Full in the Firebird config file

Comment: Have you restarted Firebird after config file change?

Comment: @Fero68: I think you just need to fix the permissions on your server's C:\Temp\ to allow Firebird access.

Comment: Or the file is locked by another process.

Comment: @Harriv: There's a different error code for "file in use". Besides, I think the initial insert creates the file, and it sounds like that's where it fails.

Comment: @Fero68: Which version of Firebird are you using. If you have the same external file defined on two database, then it could be that one Firebird Database has a lock on the file and the other DB can't access if because it is locked. try to DROP the Table from one DB because accessing by the other DB. Dropping an External Table will release any locks on the File, not delete the data in the File.

Comment: @Fero68: I tested this with my local FB Server running on windows. I created the External Table and tried to insert rows into it and got the same Error you got. I went into my Firebird.conf and noticed that my ExternalFileAccess = None.

The thing is that my file looked like this...


#ExternalFileAccess = None

Not only did I need to change the None to Full but also remove the '#' from the beginning of the line. the '#' treated the line as a comment.

ExternalFileAccess = Full

Once I did that and restarted the service it now it works.

Comment: @Ed Mendez, thanks, I just had to remove '#' from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using an external file as a table is a great way to get lots of data into Firebird quickly. However, the sample, which is from the Firebird FAQs, seems to me to be either unnecessarily complex or incorrect, because of use of smallint in table definition. As the [FB 2.5 documentation points out](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-external), "for most purposes, only columns of CHAR types would be useful."

The external file must be a text file of fixed-length records (so a .csv file won't work). The external table def should then use CHAR fields with sizes that match the lengths of the fields in each record.

Any variation in the length of the records in the text file will lead to misery (from bitter experience). I suppose the example possibly might work if all of the smallints were the same number of digits but more generically, things will go more smoothly if other formats (date, numeric) are simply expressed as CHAR in the text file by padding with spaces.

For example, if the raw data looked like this:

```
Canada 37855702
Central African Republic 4829764
Chad 16425859
Chile 19116209
China 1404676330
```

Then the text file should look like this:

```
Canada                     37855702
Central African Republic    4829764
Chad                       16425859
Chile                      19116209
China                    1404676330
```

Countries are right-padded to twenty-five characters and the (big) integers are left-padded to 10 characters, so the records are 35 characters, plus one for a line feed (*nix) or two for Window's CRLF. (Note that things get more complicated if the file uses Unicode encoding.)

The table def would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ext_test EXTERNAL '/home/dave/fbtest.txt'
(
COUNTRY CHAR(25),
POPULATION CHAR(10),
LF CHAR(1)
);
```

Make sure that the file resides on the same file system as the FB server process, that the server process has rights to the file (maybe through a FB group) and that the ExternalFileAccess parameter in firebird.conf is set appropriately - see the 2.5 documentation for details.

There are some limited things you can do with an external table, but it's most useful as a temporary transfer table, as a source for the ultimate FB table. INSERT each row from the external table into the ultimate target, casting the CHAR fields to the appropriate data types. For data of any real volume, the process runs much faster than, say, some Python code to read and feed each line individually.

If you are using an older version of FB, don't forget to DROP the external table when you're done with it to free up file locks, as outlined in the FAQs. Newer versions do this automatically. There's lots more on external tables in the 2.5 documentation at the above link.

PS - I have emailed the above to the Firebird documentation team.